# Jenkins pipeline: detect if a stage is started with the "Restart from stage" icon

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

Let's say I have a declarative pipeline. I want to run a stage only when 'Restart from stage' icon is used ?

[image]

Is there a way to do this (a method, a variable...)? I want to run the stage only if "Restart from stage" is used

```
stage('Test') {
    when {
        expression {
            // An expression to detect if Restart from this stage is used
         }
    }
    steps {
        sh 'echo 1'
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `currentBuild.getBuildCauses()`: https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/examples/#get-build-cause

Then, in your *Test stage* add `when` expression checking the cause of the build matches the one you need.

```
stage('Test') {
    when {
        expression {
            return currentBuild.getBuildCauses().any { cause ->
            cause._class == 'org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.causes.RestartDeclarativePipelineCause'
            }
        }
    }
    steps {
        sh 'echo 1'
    }
}
```

Comment: Interesting idea, and indeed when using the Restart From Stage option a new `org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.causes.RestartDeclarativePipelineCause` cause is added to the build cause and can be used for the condition. Although you will need admin approval for using `currentBuild.getBuildCauses('hudson.model.Cause$UserIdCause')`

Comment: @NoamHelmer Yes, you are right - depending on which version of Jenkins is in use script approval might be needed. According to the example in [this doc](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/examples/#get-build-cause) my understanding is that it should have been whitelisted since Jenkins 2.22

Comment: Thanks a lot @PamelaSarkisyan ! It worked for me !

Answer (score 5):

You can define a global variable that will hold a Boolean value representing if the pipeline was executed from the beginning or from a specific stage, update it in your first stage and use it later on in the `when` condition to determine if a *restart from stage* has occurred.
Something like:

```groovy
RESTART = true

pipeline {
    agent any

    stages {
        stage('Setup') {
            steps {
                script{
                    // signaling pipeline was executed from the beginning (first stage)
                    RESTART = false
                }
                // other setup steps
            }
        }
        stage('Test') {
            when {
                expression { return RESTART }
            }
            steps {
                sh 'echo 1'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Another nice option based on @Pamela's answer for using a `cause` condition, is to use the built in `triggeredBy` option in the [when directive](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#when), thus avoiding the need to use `getBuildCauses()` and the need to filter all causes, and instaed get the condition out of the box.
Something like:

```groovy
stage('Test') {
   when { triggeredBy 'RestartDeclarativePipelineCause' }
   steps {
      sh 'echo 1'
   }
}
```